# View based on semesters and year

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I have a table which contains a field BEGDATE, which is a varchar2 and contains values such as "20170405142030". I am trying to create a view which contains two fields.
The first field is the year (e.g:2017), and second field is the semester. The semester is based on the month.

```
when the month is : 01 or 02 or 03 or 04 --> then semester contains value:sem1
when the month is : 05 or 06 or 07 or 08 --> then semester contains value:sem2
when the month is : 09 or 10 or 11 or 12 --> then semester contains value:sem3.
```

I have this simple query for now :

```
 CREATE VIEW V_EMP AS
    SELECT SUBSTR(BEGDATE, 1, 4) AS ANNEE,SUBSTR(BEGDATE, 5, 2) 
    FROM EMP
```

but I am not sure how to seperate the years and relate the semesters based on the year.
Any help please?

Comment: Maybe you should better call it [Trimester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimester)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple case statement will solve your issue.

- Sem1: Month <= 04
- Sem2: Month > 04 and Month <= 08
- Sem3: Else

Keeping this in mind.

```
SELECT SUBSTR (begdate, 1, 4) AS YEAR,
       CASE
          WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) <= 4
             THEN 'Sem1'
          WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) <= 8
             THEN 'Sem2'
          ELSE 'Sem3'
       END sem
  FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the entire function but you can use DECODE:

```
SELECT DECODE (SUBSTR(BEGDATE, 5, 2), '01', 'SEM1',
               SUBSTR(BEGDATE, 5, 2), '05', 'SEM2',
               etc.)
```

You can write it more efficiently using CASE and <.